# XPath: How do I find the parent element and its class for all text nodes

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, lxml

For all text nodes, how do I find the parent element's class and tag type

Comment: Could you add sample xml and code which have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

From the [XPath documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp), it's not so difficult. Here is my on-purpose XML file:

```
<root>
    <child1>
        <text>Text1</text>
    </child1>
    <child2>
        <text>Text2</text>
    </child2>
    <child3>
        <text>Text3</text>
    </child3>
    <child4>
        <text>Text4</text>
    </child4>
</root>
```

Now with the [lxml lib](http://lxml.de/index.html) which implements XPath support (this is not the case for the built-in Python XML lib), here we are:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> root = etree.parse(path).getroot()
>>> for p in root.xpath('//text/..'):
    print p.tag


child1
child2
child3
child4
```